# Java https proxy (using https.proxyPort and https.proxyHost)

Tags: java, https, proxy

I was making a Java application that relies on setting `http.proxyPort` and `http.proxyHost`. There are two processes: One is the regular program, the other is the proxy. I have a simple socket listener running on `http.proxyPort` (which I control). It's as simple as

```
while (true) {
    try {
    Socket connection = server.accept();

    Handler handler = new Handler(connection);
    handler.start();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So whenever "process 1" makes an http request - like

```
URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.google.ca/");
URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
System.out.println(yc.getClass().getName());
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
```

It goes through the proxy. Now what if the client is using an HTTPS protocol? Like instead use `https://google.ca`? There's a property `https.proxyPort` and `https.proxyHost`, but I've literally been trying for months (on and off, it's not too important) without luck. I've read a bunch of threads (I will list some at the end so you know I have done something).

My closest attempt so far:
Server

```
try {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "test.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "2520xe");

    SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory =
            (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
    SSLServerSocket sslserversocket =
            (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(9999);
    System.out.println("Ready");
    SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslserversocket.accept();

    InputStream inputstream = sslsocket.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
    BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);

    OutputStream toClient = sslsocket.getOutputStream();
    toClient.write(("HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established\n" +
            "Content-Length: " + "Shut down!".getBytes().length
                                     + "\r\n").getBytes("utf-8"));
    toClient.write("Shut down!".getBytes("utf-8"));
    toClient.close();
} catch (Exception exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

Client

```
try {
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "9999");
    URL yahoo = new URL("https://www.google.ca/");
    URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
    System.out.println(yc.getClass().getName());
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
    System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

And I get this error `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?` I googled it but came up with some mail stuff instead.

**Basically, I need to create a java proxy server, that's set to the client by the `https.proxyPort` and `https.proxyHost` flags, and can send data back to the client app, which may not be modified in any way (it's just using `URL connection = new URL("https://...")`)**

A few of the sites I tried...

- [creating a Java Proxy Server that accepts HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357585/creating-a-java-proxy-server-that-accepts-https)
- http://stilius.net/java/java_ssl.php
- There was something else about getting Java to accept all certificates, but I can't find any of the links. I have the code, but I encountered more errors than the thing I'm doing right now, but I can include it if it helps (I didn't initially because this is already a long question)

Comment: Currently I'm also struggling with setting the system property https.proxyHost. By attaching a debugger to the VM process it seems like that the VM does not pick up the https.proxyHost property at all.

Comment: Ok, just using proxyHost and proxyPort without the http. or https. prefix now works for me. It also seems like that the behavior has (again) chnaged from Java 6 to Java 7. The statement above appleis to Java 7.

Comment: When request https URL via proxy, the client must request `CONNECT www.google.ca:443 HTTP/1.0` and proxy server responses `HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established`, both in plain. Then the client begins an SSL handshake.

Answer (score 14):

As auntyellow commented: you don't need to do any SSL-fiddling yourself. Basically https-proxying is about forwarding binary data between two parties.

To cite [draft-luotonen-web-proxy-tunneling-01.txt](http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/draft-luotonen-web-proxy-tunneling-01.txt):

> ```
>  CLIENT -> SERVER                        SERVER -> CLIENT
>  --------------------------------------  -----------------------------------
>  CONNECT home.netscape.com:443 HTTP/1.0
>  User-agent: Mozilla/4.0
>  <<< empty line >>>
>                                          HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established
>                                          Proxy-agent: Netscape-Proxy/1.1
>                                          <<< empty line >>>
>               <<< data tunneling to both directions begins >>>
> ```

So basically you need to ensure you trust your client enough to connect from your proxies firewall-position to the given host and port. Because of this common practice is to limit allowed port to 443, reject connection to localhost and from "untrusted" parties.

This is a "simple" server which is usable as `https.proxy` in Java if you are not jet convinced:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * Created for http://stackoverflow.com/q/16351413/1266906.
 */
public class Server extends Thread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new Server()).run();
    }

    public Server() {
        super("Server Thread");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9999)) {
            Socket socket;
            try {
                while ((socket = serverSocket.accept()) != null) {
                    (new Handler(socket)).start();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  // TODO: implement catch
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  // TODO: implement catch
            return;
        }
    }

    public static class Handler extends Thread {
        public static final Pattern CONNECT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("CONNECT (.+):(.+) HTTP/(1\\.[01])",
                                                                      Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        private final Socket clientSocket;
        private boolean previousWasR = false;

        public Handler(Socket clientSocket) {
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String request = readLine(clientSocket);
                System.out.println(request);
                Matcher matcher = CONNECT_PATTERN.matcher(request);
                if (matcher.matches()) {
                    String header;
                    do {
                        header = readLine(clientSocket);
                    } while (!"".equals(header));
                    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),
                                                                                   "ISO-8859-1");

                    final Socket forwardSocket;
                    try {
                        forwardSocket = new Socket(matcher.group(1), Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2)));
                        System.out.println(forwardSocket);
                    } catch (IOException | NumberFormatException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();  // TODO: implement catch
                        outputStreamWriter.write("HTTP/" + matcher.group(3) + " 502 Bad Gateway\r\n");
                        outputStreamWriter.write("Proxy-agent: Simple/0.1\r\n");
                        outputStreamWriter.write("\r\n");
                        outputStreamWriter.flush();
                        return;
                    }
                    try {
                        outputStreamWriter.write("HTTP/" + matcher.group(3) + " 200 Connection established\r\n");
                        outputStreamWriter.write("Proxy-agent: Simple/0.1\r\n");
                        outputStreamWriter.write("\r\n");
                        outputStreamWriter.flush();

                        Thread remoteToClient = new Thread() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                forwardData(forwardSocket, clientSocket);
                            }
                        };
                        remoteToClient.start();
                        try {
                            if (previousWasR) {
                                int read = clientSocket.getInputStream().read();
                                if (read != -1) {
                                    if (read != '\n') {
                                        forwardSocket.getOutputStream().write(read);
                                    }
                                    forwardData(clientSocket, forwardSocket);
                                } else {
                                    if (!forwardSocket.isOutputShutdown()) {
                                        forwardSocket.shutdownOutput();
                                    }
                                    if (!clientSocket.isInputShutdown()) {
                                        clientSocket.shutdownInput();
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                forwardData(clientSocket, forwardSocket);
                            }
                        } finally {
                            try {
                                remoteToClient.join();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();  // TODO: implement catch
                            }
                        }
                    } finally {
                        forwardSocket.close();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  // TODO: implement catch
            } finally {
                try {
                    clientSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();  // TODO: implement catch
                }
            }
        }

        private static void forwardData(Socket inputSocket, Socket outputSocket) {
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = inputSocket.getInputStream();
                try {
                    OutputStream outputStream = outputSocket.getOutputStream();
                    try {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                        int read;
                        do {
                            read = inputStream.read(buffer);
                            if (read > 0) {
                                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
                                if (inputStream.available() < 1) {
                                    outputStream.flush();
                                }
                            }
                        } while (read >= 0);
                    } finally {
                        if (!outputSocket.isOutputShutdown()) {
                            outputSocket.shutdownOutput();
                        }
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (!inputSocket.isInputShutdown()) {
                        inputSocket.shutdownInput();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  // TODO: implement catch
            }
        }

        private String readLine(Socket socket) throws IOException {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int next;
            readerLoop:
            while ((next = socket.getInputStream().read()) != -1) {
                if (previousWasR && next == '\n') {
                    previousWasR = false;
                    continue;
                }
                previousWasR = false;
                switch (next) {
                    case '\r':
                        previousWasR = true;
                        break readerLoop;
                    case '\n':
                        break readerLoop;
                    default:
                        byteArrayOutputStream.write(next);
                        break;
                }
            }
            return byteArrayOutputStream.toString("ISO-8859-1");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not bad. There's a wrinkle. When the proxy reads EOS from one socket it should shutdown the other socket for output and exit that thread. When it has shutdown both sockets it can then close them both and exit the second thread. This helps in HTTP keep-alive situations.

Comment: @EJP Thank you for the feedback! I switched to [calling the shutdown-methods](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3626450/1266906) and added a finally-closer to the `forwardSocket`. Did I miss something else?

Comment: I just utilized this and did one more trick to solve the problem of creating http proxy that routes traffic using another socks proxy...

java -DproxySet=true -DsocksProxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DsocksProxyPort=8080 HttpServer

My need: I have socks proxy available to route traffic but many apps does not support socks, so I need an adaptor that act as http proxy and trasfer traffic to socks proxy... Java already have built in support for socks proxy adaptor and this program act as htttp  proxy and wholla... my problem solved...

Answer (score 1):

Default java SE7 implementation of URLConnection for HTTPS protocol uses parameters
**https.proxyHost** and **https.proxyPort**

Add to Tomcat:

> -Dhttps.proxyHost="192.168.121.31" -Dhttps.proxyPort="3128"